# How to prevent exited with code 1 when no changes in database in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, docker, nestjs, typeorm

I set up the migrations. I am using PostgreSQL. If there are changes in entities everything is OK. But when there are no changes my entities TypeORM exists with code 1 with error message "No changes in database schema were found". Hence my docker container terminates its own. I do not want to this. If there are no changes just skip this do not exit with code 1. How can I do that?

I tried to create empty migration file with typeorm migration create but it does not effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m experiencing this right now too. In my case I kind of blindly followed loosely what other projects in my org are doing.. they all seem to have an automated migrations (script generation and migration running) phases to container creation and deployment..

So right now I’m having to step back and question whether an automated migration step should always run when we deploy new code changes .. or if they should only be a manual process *(which seems sketchy.. prone to mistake).*

Because this particular feature of the TypeORM CLI fails container creation phase each time when **no changes need to be made.**

Looking through the TypeORM source code I’ve found a set of options/flags that can be passed to the migration generate command .. specifically a **“ch”** option .. or what is likely `--ch` on the command line .. This flag is apparently *supposed* to allow a 0-exit with a simple message “no changes in db schema exist. No migration generated” .. However I haven’t yet figured out where to place it because of the inherently convoluted way TypeORM has their CLI set up.
I will get back and update once I’ve exhausted all options.

**Update:** So I got the `--ch` flag to work, but in a bit of comedy, this flag will fail with exit-status 1 anytime you **do have** changes between your db and source that need to be syncd.. So.. This isn't a viable option. Apparently typeorm must have a strong opinion on when migration generation should be done, and they don't provide for a way to do it automatically without either failing when **no** changes need to be syncd or conversely failing when changes **do** exist that need to be sync'd..

So I'm going to try to move the process out of my build flow somehow.